# Single code in all layer

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

If you have a method in the backend and you want to reuse the code in the frontend without having the same source code for C# and javascript.

I would like to have a single code no matter what programming code you use? Is it possible to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: You meant to call those common methods both from C# and from JavaScript, right?

Comment: Sanish - yes...

Answer (score 0):

We can do that in ASP.NET MVC. From your JavaScript, you can call an action method using AJAX syntax. If you have data to be passed from your action method to JavaScript, you will need to return a JSON object to JavaScript. Basically you are calling an ACTION METHOD inside your MVC Controller. In your action method you can call another common function placed in same class library or another class library so you can reuse the method that process your data. There are many examples available online about how to access your action methods from JavaScript.

Eg: [Example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-jQuery-AJAX-and-JSON-Example.aspx)